# How can I get Filled(columns that have not Empty and Not Null Values) Columns Count in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Can anyone please help me get the count of the filled MySQL columns?

For example:
My Table Structure:

| ID | FName | LName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | NULL |
| 2 |  | XYZ |

---

In the above table, I have two Rows, and both rows contain one Null and One Empty Value, I just need to get the Count of each row that doesn't have `NULL` OR `EMPTY` Value for a specific `ID`.

---

Expected Result:

WHERE ID=1, the result would be: 
Count = 2 (ID, FName)

WHERE ID=2, the result would be: 
Count = 2 (ID, LName)

---

**I want to use this in WordPress

Comment: Can you explain the expected result for `ID = 2`?  Shouldn't the count be 1?

Comment: Test each column against (not empty and not NULL) separately and summarize testing results.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So for `ID = 2`, the count would be two because It will include the counting of that particular ID too.

Comment: @Akina I have currently got the Database Table results as an array and currently, I'm looping through that particular array using PHP foreach, and comparing the Not Null and Not empty Value, and increasing the COUNT, but is that good for optimization?

Answer (score 0):

So, after searching for an hour or two.

I'm using this as my solution but I'm not sure if it's good regrading the optimization. Here is what I'm using:

```
function ranking_mechanism( $currentUserID ){
global $wpdb;
$rank = 0;

$results = $wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID=%d', $currentUserID)
); 

$finalArr = (array) $results; // Convert $results as Array(to perform iteration), it(WordPress DB Query) typically return Object by Default 
foreach ( $finalArr as $key => $Table ) {
    if( $finalArr[$key] == '' || $finalArr[$key] == 'NULL' ){
        // Nothing to do 
    }else{
        $rank = $rank+1; // Increase Rank If Found Value
    }
    return $rank;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT ID,   (ID IS NOT NULL) /* assuming that ID is numeric and cannot be empty string */
           + (FName <> '' AND FName IS NOT NULL) 
           + (LName <> '' AND LName IS NOT NULL) AS `Count`
FROM source_table
-- WHERE ID = ???
```